# How to style rocky coast?

Tags: qgis, style, terrain

I've got a bunch of data from LINZ which includes rocky areas. Is it possible to style them as they do (see picture)? It's a fairly standard style in large scale maps so I hoped it would be simple!

I'm using QGIS but I'm relatively new to it

[image]

Comment: Are they lines or polygons? Check [How to create custom styles in QGIS](https://gisinecology.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-create-custom-styles-in-qgis/)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve something similar with a marker line with variable-size rectangular markers. 
[image]
Tweak the values in the data-defined marker size expression to get the right variation in size.

> rand(1,3)*0.3+2

[image]

You can get closer to the desired result by substituting a custom marker, shaped like this: |_|